DCGAN for mammograms
I'm currently working on a DCGAN with Wasserstein Distance Gradient Penalty (WGAN-GP) for mammograms. The target mammograms are in 4D, as I'm using SD VAE 1.4 to reduce the complexity. Each of the images are (4, 128, 128).
This is the code summarized as I could:
import os
import glob
import yaml
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img
from tensorflow.keras import layers

with open('config_dcgan.yaml', 'r') as file:
    config = yaml.safe_load(file)

def find_latest_checkpoint(path_pattern):
    list_of_files = glob.glob(path_pattern)
    if list_of_files:
        latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
        return latest_file
    return None

def preprocess_image_pair(target_path, latent_paths, latent_size=(128, 128), target_size=(1024, 1024)):
    target_image = load_img(target_path, target_size=target_size, color_mode='grayscale')
    target_image = img_to_array(target_image)
    latent_image = np.zeros((*latent_size, 4), dtype=np.float32)
    for i, latent_path in enumerate(latent_paths):
        img = load_img(latent_path, target_size=latent_size, color_mode='grayscale')
        img = img_to_array(img)
        latent_image[:, :, i] = img[:, :, 0]
    return target_image.astype(np.float32), latent_image

def create_dataset(image_folder, batch_size, target_size, latent_size):
    target_image_paths = [path for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(image_folder, '*.png')) if "_latent_" not in path]
    def generate_pairs(target_path):
        base_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(target_path))[0].decode("utf-8")
        latent_paths = [os.path.join(image_folder, f"{base_name}_latent_{i}.png") for i in range(4)]
        target_image, latent_images = preprocess_image_pair(target_path, latent_paths, target_size=target_size)
        return target_image, latent_images
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(target_image_paths)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.numpy_function(func=generate_pairs, inp=[x], Tout=[tf.float32, tf.float32]),
                          num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (tf.reshape(x, target_size + (1,)), tf.reshape(y, latent_size + (4,))))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    return dataset

def make_generator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(4*4*1024, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.Reshape((4, 4, 1024)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1024, (3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(2048, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(2048, (3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1024, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1024, (3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(512, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(4, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False),
    ])
    return model

def make_discriminator_model(input_shape=[128, 128, 4]):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', input_shape=input_shape),
        layers.LeakyReLU(),
        layers.Dropout(0.3),
        layers.Conv2D(128, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
        layers.LeakyReLU(),
        layers.Dropout(0.3),
        layers.Conv2D(256, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
        layers.LeakyReLU(),
        layers.Dropout(0.3),
        layers.Conv2D(512, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
        layers.LeakyReLU(),
        layers.Dropout(0.3),
        layers.Conv2D(1024, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
        layers.LeakyReLU(),
        layers.Dropout(0.3),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(1),
    ])
    return model

def gradient_penalty(batch_size, real_images, fake_images, discriminator):
    alpha = tf.random.normal([batch_size, 1, 1, 1], 0.0, 1.0)
    diff = fake_images - real_images
    interpolated = real_images + alpha * diff
    with tf.GradientTape() as gp_tape:
        gp_tape.watch(interpolated)
        pred = discriminator(interpolated, training=True)
    grads = gp_tape.gradient(pred, [interpolated])[0]
    norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(grads), axis=[1, 2, 3]))
    gradient_penalty = tf.reduce_mean((norm - 1.0) ** 2)
    return gradient_penalty

def discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output, gradient_penalty, lambda_gp):
    loss = fake_output - real_output + lambda_gp * gradient_penalty
    return loss

def generator_loss(fake_output):
    return -tf.reduce_mean(fake_output)


strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
print('Number of devices: {}'.format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))

with strategy.scope():
    # Attempt to load the latest generator and discriminator models
    latest_generator = find_latest_checkpoint(config['model_paths']['generator'] + "/*.keras")
    latest_discriminator = find_latest_checkpoint(config['model_paths']['discriminator'] + "/*.keras")

    if latest_generator and latest_discriminator:
        generator = tf.keras.models.load_model(latest_generator)
        discriminator = tf.keras.models.load_model(latest_discriminator)
        initial_epoch = int(latest_generator.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0])
        print(f"Resuming training from epoch {initial_epoch}")
    else:
        generator = make_generator_model()
        discriminator = make_discriminator_model()
        initial_epoch = 0
        print("Starting training from scratch")

    generator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)
    discriminator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)

losses_path = 'losses.npy'
if os.path.exists(losses_path):
    losses = np.load(losses_path).tolist()
    print("Loaded existing loss data")
else:
    losses = []
    print("Starting new loss data tracking")

@tf.function
def train_step(dist_inputs):
    def step_fn(inputs):
        target_images, batch_size, lambda_gp = inputs
        noise = tf.random.normal([batch_size, 100])
        with tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
            generated_images = generator(noise, training=True)
            real_output = discriminator(target_images, training=True)
            fake_output = discriminator(generated_images, training=True)
            gp = gradient_penalty(batch_size, target_images, generated_images, discriminator)
            d_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output, gp, lambda_gp)
        gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(d_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)
        discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator.trainable_variables))

        with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape:
            generated_images = generator(noise, training=True)
            fake_output = discriminator(generated_images, training=True)
            g_loss = generator_loss(fake_output)
        gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(g_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
        generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
        return d_loss, g_loss

    per_replica_losses = strategy.run(step_fn, args=(dist_inputs,))
    return strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, per_replica_losses, axis=None)

train_dataset = create_dataset(config['image_folder'], config['batch_size'], tuple(config['target_size']), tuple(config['latent_size']))

for epoch in range(initial_epoch + 1, config['epochs'] + 1):
    epoch_losses = []  
    for target_images_batch, latent_images_batch in train_dataset:
        d_loss, g_loss = train_step((latent_images_batch, config['batch_size'], config['lambda_gp']))
        epoch_losses.append((d_loss.numpy(), g_loss.numpy()))
    mean_d_loss = np.mean([loss[0] for loss in epoch_losses])
    mean_g_loss = np.mean([loss[1] for loss in epoch_losses])
    losses.append((float(mean_d_loss), float(mean_g_loss)))
    print(f"Epoch {epoch}/{config['epochs']} - Discriminator Loss: {mean_d_loss}, Generator Loss: {mean_g_loss}")

    if epoch % config['save_epochs'] == 0 or epoch == config['epochs']:
        noise = tf.random.normal([1, 100])
        generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)
        generated_image_path = config['generated_images_path']
        os.makedirs(generated_image_path, exist_ok=True)
        np.save(f"{generated_image_path}/generated_image_{epoch}.npy", generated_image.numpy())

        generator.save(f"{config['model_paths']['generator']}/generator_model_{epoch}.keras")
        discriminator.save(f"{config['model_paths']['discriminator']}/discriminator_model_{epoch}.keras")
        losses_array = np.array(losses)
        np.save(losses_path, losses_array)

        print(f"Models and losses saved at epoch {epoch}")

The lambda I'm using is 10. The problem here is that I'm getting a really poor performance. This is the loss curve:

Notice how it flattens somehow, but the loss is really high (1e8 scale).
I don't know if it is something wrong with the implementation of the losses or with something in my code; or perhaps there is something missing in the architecture.
If someone knows or can give me some advice on how to improve these results I would appreciate it.
Thanks.
